# Preg replace in preg replace callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How I can change the following code preg_replace (deprecated in PHP 5.6):

`$ Encoded = preg_replace ('/ ([\ 000- \ 011 \ 013 \ 014 \ 016- \ 037 \ 075 \ 077 \ 137 \ 177- \ 377]) / and',
               "'='. Sprintf ('% 02X', ord ('\\ 1'))", $ encoded);`

with `preg_replace_callback`?

Comment: Could you please format it correctly? Please also provide an example string.

Comment: Try `$encoded = preg_replace_callback('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])\/and/', function($m) {
 return  '='. sprintf('%02X', ord($m[1]));
}, $encoded);`

Comment: Excellent  Wiktor, now it all seems ok. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [**`preg_replace_callback`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) like this:

```
$re = '/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077‌​\137\177-\377])\/and‌​/';
$encoded = preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) { 
     return '='. sprintf('%02X', ord($m[1])); 
}, $encoded);
```

where `$m` is the match object containing the match and optional captures that you may acces via indices. E.g. `$m[1]` is the capture group #1 value (ie. of the `([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077‌​\137\177-\377])` subpattern).